# Regex Pattern - Allow alpha numeric, a bunch of special chars, but not a certain sequence of chars

Tags: regex, validation, match

I have the following regex:

```
(?!^[&#]*$)^([A-Za-z0-9-'.,&@:?!()$#/\\]*)$
```

So allow A-Z, a-Z, 0-9, and these special chars `'.,&@:?!()$#/\`

I want to NOT match if the following set of chars is encountered anywhere in the string in this order:

```
&#
```

When I run this regex with just "&#" as input, it does not match my pattern, I get an error, great. When I run the regex with `'.,&@:?!()$#/\ABC123` It does match my pattern, no errors.

However when I run it with:

```
'.,&#@:?!()$#/\ABC123
```

It does not error either. I'm doing something wrong with the check for the &# sequence.

Can someone tell me what I've done wrong, I'm not great with these things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Borrowing a technique for matching quoted strings, remove `&` from your character class, add an alternative for `&` **not** followed by `#`, and allow the string to optionally end with `&`:

> `^((?:[A-Za-z0-9-'.,@:?!()$#/\\]+|&[^#])*&?)$`

Comment: This would also allow sequences like “&∆” whereas ∆ is one of `[^#]`, e. g. “_”, “<”, “>”, etc. So the following would be better:
    ^(?:[A-Za-z0-9-'.,@:?!()$#/\\]+|&[A-Za-z0-9-'.,@:?!()$/\\])*$

Answer (score 1):

I would actually do it in two parts:

1. Check your allowed character set.  To do this I would look for characters that are not allowed, and return false if there's a match.  That means I have a nice simple expression:
   `[^A-Za-z0-9'\.&@:?!()$#^]`
2. Check your banned substring.  And since it is just a substring, I probably wouldn't even use a regex for that part.

You didn't mention your language, but if in C#:

```
bool IsValid(string input)
{
    return !(   input.Contains("&#")  
               || Regex.IsMatch(@"[^A-Za-z0-9'\.&@:?!()$#^]", input) 
            );
}
```

Comment: yeah I agree, and that's how I'd do it normally, but see below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Perl compatible RegExp

To not match on the string '&#':

> `(?![^&]*&#)^([A-Za-z0-9-'.,&@:?!()$#/\\]*)$`

Although you don't need the parenthesis because you are matching the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

`^((?!&#)[A-Za-z0-9-'.,&@:?!()$#/\\])*$`

note that the last \ is escaped (doubled)
SO automatically turns `\\` into \ if not in backticks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using two regular expressions in a conditional:

```
    if (string has sequence "&#")
      return false
    else
      return (string matches sequence "A-Za-z0-9-'.,&@:?!()$#/\")
```

I believe your second "main" regex of

```
^([A-Za-z0-9-'.,&@:?!()$#/\])$"
```

has several errors:

- It will test only one character in your set
- The `\` character in regular expressions is a token indicating that the next character is part of some sort of "class" of characters (ex. `\n` = is the line feed character).  The character sequence `\]` is actually causing your bracketed list not to be terminated.

You may be better off using

```
^[A-Za-z0-9-'.,&@:?!()$#/\\]+$
```

Note that the slash character is represented by a double-slash.

The `+` character indicates that at least one character being tested has to match the regex; if it is fine to pass a zero-length string, replace the `+` with a `*`.

Comment: The errors you pointed out weren't entirely the OP's fault.  The forum software ate a couple of asterisks and a backslash.  That's what happens when you try to talk about regexes without code-ifying them.

Comment: By the way, if John really had accidentally escaped the closing square bracket, the regex wouldn't even have compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, although Ben Blank's regex works, it's more complicated than it needs to be. I would do it like this:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9-'.,@:?!()$#/\\]+|&(?!#))+$
```

Because I used a negative lookahead instead of a negated character class, the regex doesn't need any extra help to match an ampersand at the end of the string.